# HDF5 error while compiling another library

Tags: cmake, clang, hdf5

I have compiled HDF5 following these steps:

```
untar hdf5-xxx.tar.gz
cd hdf5-xxx
make
make install
```

However, while I install another library (OpenGM), which request HDF5, I give the following arguments:

```
HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY                /Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5                                                             
 HDF5_CPP_LIBRARY                 /Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/c++                                                              
 HDF5_HL_LIBRARY                  /Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl                                                               
 HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR                 /Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5/include                                                     
 HDF5_Z_LIBRARY                   /usr/lib/libz.dylib
```

After using CMake and generate, I get:

```
 WARNING: Target "example-io" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to libraries.
  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "example-io" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "external-library-daoopt" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only
 to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "external-library-daoopt" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link only to
 libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "external-library-daoopt-shared" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may
 link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "external-library-daoopt-shared" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link
 only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "_opengmcore" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to
 libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "_opengmcore" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to
 libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "_opengmcore" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "_hdf5" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "_hdf5" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake
 is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "modelIO" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "modelIO" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hl".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.

 WARNING: Target "buildFoE" requests linking to directory "/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/hdf5".  Targets may link only to libraries.
 CMake is dropping the item.
```

As those are "just" warnings, I can compile my OpenGM library:

```
make
```

But I thus end up with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_H5Aclose", referenced from:
      void marray::hdf5::save<unsigned long>(int const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, marray::Marray<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&) in io_graphical_model.cxx.o
      void marray::hdf5::save<float>(int const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, marray::Marray<float, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&) in io_graphical_model.cxx.o
      void marray::hdf5::save<double>(int const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, marray::Marray<double, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&) in io_graphical_model.cxx.o
      void marray::hdf5::save<long>(int const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, marray::Marray<long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> > const&) in io_graphical_model.cxx.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As both warnings and the error deal with HDF5, I suppose the main problem comes from this library.

I am using MacOSX if it can help.

**EDIT:**Add the FindHDF5.cmake file

```
# - Find HDF5, a library for reading and writing self describing array data.
#
FIND_PATH(HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR hdf5.h)

FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY NAMES hdf5dll hdf5  )
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_HL_LIBRARY NAMES hdf5_hldll hdf5_hl  )
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_CPP_LIBRARY NAMES hdf5_cppdll hdf5_cpp )

IF(WIN32 AND HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY MATCHES "dll.lib$")
    SET(HDF5_CFLAGS "-D_HDF5USEDLL_")
    SET(HDF5_CPPFLAGS "-D_HDF5USEDLL_ -DHDF5CPP_USEDLL")
ELSE()
    SET(HDF5_CFLAGS)
    SET(HDF5_CPPFLAGS)
ENDIF()

SET(HDF5_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
SET(HDF5_VERSION_MINOR 8)

set(HDF5_SUFFICIENT_VERSION FALSE)

TRY_COMPILE(HDF5_SUFFICIENT_VERSION
            ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/checkHDF5version.c
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-I\"${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR}\" -DMIN_MAJOR=${HDF5_VERSION_MAJOR} -DMIN_MINOR=${HDF5_VERSION_MINOR}")

if(HDF5_SUFFICIENT_VERSION)
    MESSAGE(STATUS
           "Checking HDF5 version (at least ${HDF5_VERSION_MAJOR}.${HDF5_VERSION_MINOR}): ok")
else()
    MESSAGE( STATUS "HDF5: need at least version ${HDF5_VERSION_MAJOR}.${HDF5_VERSION_MINOR}" )
endif()

set(HDF5_USES_ZLIB FALSE)
TRY_COMPILE(HDF5_USES_ZLIB
           ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/checkHDF5usesCompression.c
           COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-I\"${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR}\" -DH5_SOMETHING=H5_HAVE_FILTER_DEFLATE")

if(HDF5_USES_ZLIB)
    FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_Z_LIBRARY NAMES zlib1 zlib z )
    set(HDF5_ZLIB_OK ${HDF5_Z_LIBRARY})
else()
    set(HDF5_ZLIB_OK TRUE)
    set(HDF5_Z_LIBRARY "")
endif()

set(HDF5_USES_SZLIB FALSE)
TRY_COMPILE(HDF5_USES_SZLIB 
            ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/checkHDF5usesCompression.c
            COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-I\"${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR}\" -DH5_SOMETHING=H5_HAVE_FILTER_SZIP")

if(HDF5_USES_SZLIB)
    FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY NAMES szlibdll sz )
    set(HDF5_SZLIB_OK ${HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY})
else()
    set(HDF5_SZLIB_OK TRUE)
    set(HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY "")
endif()

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set HDF5_FOUND to TRUE if 
# all listed variables are TRUE
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(HDF5 DEFAULT_MSG HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY 
        HDF5_HL_LIBRARY HDF5_ZLIB_OK HDF5_SZLIB_OK HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR)

IF(HDF5_FOUND)
    SET(HDF5_LIBRARIES ${HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY} ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARY} ${HDF5_Z_LIBRARY} ${HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY})
ELSE()
    SET(HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
    SET(HDF5_HL_LIBRARY   HDF5_HL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
    SET(HDF5_Z_LIBRARY    HDF5_Z_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
    SET(HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY   HDF5_SZ_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
ENDIF(HDF5_FOUND)
```

Comment: `... where I provide the path to the HDF5 library ...` - Looks like you assign **directory** to a variable, which expects to be a **library file**. That is why you have given warnings.

Comment: See my edit to see what I have given as CMake arguments.

Comment: Exactly that I said before: You assign *directories* to variables (`HDF5_CORE_LIBRARY`, `HDF5_HL_LIBRARY`), which should be a **library files**.

Comment: What do you define by library? Which extensions should I consider?

Comment: You get this list of variables via `find_package(HDF5)`, don't you? Instead of filling this variables *manually*, it is better to **hint** this procedure where you install HDF5 library. Comments in the `FindHDF5.cmake` script describe how you can hint it. Just follow them.

Comment: I have rarely used CMake (just to install some libraries such as OpenCV, where I only gave the path to directories), so I do not completely understand what you mean. I add the FindHDF5.cmake to my first post. I have however found libraries files such as libhdf5.a, libhdf5_hl.a.

Comment: I gave dylib files as libraries.

Comment: However, I do not manage to find any libhdf5_cpp.dylib file...

Comment: `However, I do not manage to find any libhdf5_cpp.dylib file...` - Looks like this library is missed in your installation. Try to find HDF5 with cpp library. I am not familiar with HDF5, but directory `/Users/Florian/Documents/THESE/hdf5-1.8.7/c++` - does it contain any library? It could be this library is just a replacement for `hdf5_cpp`. Note, that most of Find scripts are written not by the packages authors, so incompatibilites may occures.

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten to provide the --with_cxx flag while compiling HDF5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by compiling the HDF5 library with the `--with_cxx` flag to build the C++ interface. In addition, I installed the HDF5 library in `/usr/local` so that it is automatically found when installing opengm.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The problem is though, despite the fact I can successfully compile OpenGM, I cannot compile a simple c++ file that calls opengm libraries and hdf5.